# How can I take a Java Set of size X and break into X/Y Sets?

Tags: java, set, hashset

I have a Java Set (specifically HashSet). Suppose it has a size of 10k. How can I break it into 5 Sets each of size 2k?

Comment: Is there some specific rule that you want to use while distributing elements into these 5 subsets?

Comment: @Pshemo: No specific rule is needed. I could do as nhahtdh suggested. I thought I was just overlooking a lib call like a List.subList

Comment: @James That's what the JavaDoc is for: [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This method will split the elements of the set so that the first set contains the first 2000, the second contains the next 2000, etc.

```
public static <T> List<Set<T>> split(Set<T> original, int count) {
    // Create a list of sets to return.
    ArrayList<Set<T>> result = new ArrayList<Set<T>>(count);

    // Create an iterator for the original set.
    Iterator<T> it = original.iterator();

    // Calculate the required number of elements for each set.
    int each = original.size() / count;

    // Create each new set.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        HashSet<T> s = new HashSet<T>(original.size() / count + 1);
        result.add(s);
        for (int j = 0; j < each && it.hasNext(); j++) {
            s.add(it.next());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

//As example, in your code...

Set<Integer> originalSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
// [fill the set...]
List<Set<Integer>> splitSets = split(originalSet, 5);
Set<Integer> first = splitSets.get(0); // etc.
```

Comment: j.add(it.next()) => s.add(it.next()); I think so

Comment: In case of 5 elements being divided to page having 2 elements, your code gives 2 pages with 2 elements. The last one is lost. Therefore ```i < count``` => ```i <= count```

Answer (score 27):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has libraries to partition Iterable classes. The [Iterables](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.java) is a utility class which has static methods to partition Iterable classes. The return value is a Iterable of lists though. The given code shows how to do that.

```
Set<Integer> myIntSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
// fill the set
Iterable<List<Integer>> lists = Iterables.partition(myIntSet, SIZE_EACH_PARTITION);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write it by your own have a look at [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). The Lists class have a method partition(List, int) to split a list into multiple lists with the specified size.
See [Guava Lists](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Lists)

Answer (score 0):

I've written something that does the splitting of the set.

It uses intermediate arrays and Lists.

It uses the Arrays.asList and the Arrays.copyOfRange methods.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class SetSplitTest {
    //define and initialize set
    private static Set<Integer> largeSet;
    static {
        largeSet  = new HashSet<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            largeSet.add(i);
        }
    }


    public static void main() {
        System.out.println(largeSet);
        int amountOfSets = 5; //amount of subsets wanted
        Set<Integer>[] subsets = new Set[amountOfSets]; //array holding the subsets

        Integer[] largesetarray =  largeSet.toArray(new Integer[largeSet.size()]);

        for (int i = 1; i <= amountOfSets; i++) {
            int fromIndex = (i-1) * largeSet.size() / amountOfSets;
            int toIndex = i * largeSet.size() / amountOfSets - 1; 
            Set<Integer> subHashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
            subHashSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(largesetarray, fromIndex, toIndex)));

            subsets[i - 1] = subHashSet;
        }

        for (Set<Integer> subset : subsets) {
            System.out.println(subset);
        }
    }
}
```

This definately not the most elegant solution, but it's the best i could think off at the moment when not wanting to loop the sets yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Late Answer but you can try,

1. By converting it as List, Using Guava library to use `Lists.partition(list, PARTITION_VALUE)`.

   Dependency:

   ```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
         <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
         <version>31.1-jre</version>
     </dependency>
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
   import java.util.*;
   .
   .
   Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
   //Fill data to hashSet
   List<String> hashSetAsList = new ArrayList<>(hashSet);
   List<List<String>> partitionedLists = Lists.partition(hashSetAsList, PARTITION_VALUE);
   ```
2. By using `List.subList(INDEX_START,INDEX_END)`

   ```
   import java.util.*;
   .
   .
   List<String> hashSetAsList = new ArrayList<>(hashSet);
   List<String> subList = hashSetAsList.subList(INDEX_START,INDEX_END);
   //INDEX_END will be excluded
   ```
3. By Converting it to TreeSet & SortedSet and using `Set.subSet(INDEX_START,INDEX_END)` ... this way set will be sorted

   ```
   Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
   SortedSet<String> sortedHashSet= new TreeSet<>(hashSet);
   Set<String> subSet_1 = sortedHashSet.subSet(INDEX_START,INDEX_END);
   //INDEX_END will be excluded
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Iterate over the entire set, and add the first 2000 elements to a first new set, the 2nd 2000 elements to the 2nd new set, etc.