# Is there a more efficient way to reduce Java TreeSet to a subset based on index?

Tags: java, treeset

I am currently implementing the Mash algorithm for genome comparison. For this I need to create a sketch S(A) for each genome, which is a set of certain size `s` containing the lowest hash values corresponding to k-mers in the genome. To compare two genomes, I am computing the Jaccard index, for which I need an additional sketch of the union of the two genomes, i.e. S(A u B) for two genomes A and B. This should contain the `s` lowest hash values found in the union of A and B.

I am computing the sketches as a `TreeSet` because in the original algorithm to compute a sketch I need to remove the biggest value from the set whenever I add a new value that is lower and the sketch has already reached the maximum size `s`. This is very easily accomplished using `TreeSet` because the largest value will be in the last position of the set.

I have computed a union of two sketches and now want to remove the larger elements to reduce the sketch size to size `s`. I first implemented this using a `while` loop and removing the last element until reaching the desired size.

The following is my code using an example `TreeSet` and size `s` = 10:

```
SortedSet<Integer> example = new TreeSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    example.add(i);
}

while (example.size() > 10) example.remove(example.last());
```

However, in the real application sketch sizes will be much larger and the size of the union can be up to two times the size of a single sketch. Trying to find a more efficient way to reduce the sketch size I found that you could convert the `TreeSet` to an array. Thus, my second approach would be the following:

```
Object[] temp = example.toArray();
int value = (int) temp[10];
example = example.headSet(value);
```

So, here I am getting the value at index `s` from the array, which I can then use to create a `headSet` from the `TreeSet`.

Now, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to reduce the size of the `TreeSet`, where I don't need to iterate over the size of the `TreeSet` over and over again or generate an extra array.

Comment: `TreeSet` does not have great native support for this use case, but a custom binary tree could do better.  That's a lot of work, though.

Comment: would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296888/2774232 ?

Comment: @corneliu: that doesn't particularly benefit efficiency in this case.

Comment: Do you need to mutate this collection?  Or just have something sorted?  A sorted list might actually be ideal.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am not sure that I understand exactly what it means to mutate the collection. When generating the union `TreeSet` I generate it from one of the previous sets (`TreeSet<Integer> union = new TreeSet<>(sketchA);`) and then add the second set using the `addAll` function (`union.addAll(sketchB);`). After this step I only need to remove the overhang, i.e. the highest values, to get a set of size `s`.